# macOS: Notarize in Script?

Tags: macos, notarize

Because the codesigning and archiving by Xcode is time-consuming, boring and problematic, I've always codesigned, archived and shipped my Developer ID signed macOS app using the command-line tools `xcodebuild`, `codesign`, etc. via my own script.  Notarizing looks like it is going to be a major pain.  Is it possible to add notarizing to my script?

Answer (score 39):

Yes.  Unfortunately, the [official answer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow?language=objc) leaves some loose ends, for example this [important tidbit from Quinn "the Eskimo"](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113798).  Here is how to do it:

### One-Time Setups

#### Get an App-Specific Password

Decide on a name for your "app" of notarizing apps.  I use the name of my product-shipping script, `SSYShipProduct.pl` because this is the "app" which will use this password.  We shall refer to whatever name you compose as *your-notarizing-name*.

Browse to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage, scroll to *Security* > *App-Specific Password*, and generate an *App-Specific* password for an *app* named *your-notarizing-name*.  Copy the password that it gives you.  We shall call that *app-specific-password*.

#### Add the App-Specific password to your macOS Keychain

Run this command to add the password you just created to your keychain:

`security add-generic-password -a "your-apple-ID-email" -w "app-specific-password" -s "your-notarizing-name"`

The `-s` parameter is the name that this item will have in your Keychain.  I think you could actually use a different name, but in my mind it makes sense to use `your-notarizing-name` here too.

You can verify that it worked by searching in the *Keychain Access* application.  However, be aware that new items are not listed in *Keychain Access* until after you quit and relaunch it.

#### Maybe, get the relevant *itc-provider*

If your Apple ID is associated with more than one Apple Developer Connection team (such as if you do contract work), you will need the *itc_provider* of the team for which this app should be notarized.

To find the *itc_provider* of your team, execute this command:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m provider -u "your-apple-ID-email" -p "app-specific-password"`

Scroll to the end of the output printed by this command and look at the *Provider listing* table.  Copy the *Short Name* of the desired team.  We shall call this "developer-team-itc-provider".

### For each shipment (Scriptable!)

If you sign components of your app using the `/usr/bin/codesign` command line tool, each invocation of codesign must have the following new argument parameter , which tells codesign to sign with the so-called *hardened runtime*:

```
 `--options runtime`
```

Conversely if your app is signed in Xcode, you must set the Build Setting *Hardened runtime*, available in Xcode 10 or later, to *Yes* in all executable component targets.

Other than that, your script should create a build of your app in Release configuration and codesign it, same as in pre-notarization days.

#### Upload to Apple Notary service

Your script should then archive your app to a .zip or .dmg.  Note that this is an interim file which will only be uploaded to the Apple Notary service, not shipped.

Then, your script should compose a *primary bundle ID value*, which will be your app's bundle identifier with `.zip` or `.dmg` appended.  Example: *your-pbid-value* = `com.mycompany.YourApp.zip`.

In what follows, your script will use `altool`, which is Apple's name for *Application Loader Tool*.

Your script should then run this command to get your .zip or .dmg notarized:

`/usr/bin/xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "your-pbid-value" --username "your-apple-id-email" --password "@keychain:your-notarizing-name" -itc_provider "developer-team-itc-provider" --file /path/to/YourApp.zip/or/YourApp.dmg --output-format "xml"`

(Note that, in the above command, oddly, all argument names are preceded by two dashes except `-itc_provider` is preceded by only one dash.  Also, if the scripting language you are using interpolates `@` characters in strings, code it to prevent interpolation of `@keychain`).

After a minute or so, `xcrun` will exit and print to stdout some XML which, if your submission was *accepted* (note: not *approved* yet), will look like this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>notarization-upload</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestUUID</key>
        <string>2ab59b26-19ec-4a30-84cf-6d2cb8d3c97e</string>
    </dict>
    <key>os-version</key>
    <string>10.15.0</string>
    <key>success-message</key>
    <string>No errors uploading 'path/to/YourApp.zip'.</string>
    <key>tool-path</key>
    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework</string>
    <key>tool-version</key>
    <string>1.1.1138</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

All you really need out of there is that `RequestUUID` value.  However, since I ship four apps often, and because it ruins my day when my shipping script fails without providing helpful error information, and because (see below) you are going to make another call which also returns interesting XML, I invested some time in adding to my script a subroutine which takes two parameters, XML and a key path, and returns the value of the XML at a given key path.  In the case above, I call this subroutine to get the `RequestUUID`, and then again to get the `success-message`.

(My script is in Perl.  Although there is available in CPAN a module named *XML::Simple* which can do this parsing in a line or two, it is marked by the maintainer as not for use in new designs.  So, to avoid needing to install and wrangle with a *real* XML parser, I opted instead to use `PlistBuddy` as suggested in the comment by @khuttun. This was slightly painful also because, unfortunately, `altool` does not have an option to write its output to a file, and `PlistBuddy` is not documented to accept stdin.  So my subroutine writes the stdout from `altool` to a temporary file, and then passes that temporary file's path to PlistBuddy.  Kind of disgusting, but it works.)

#### Delete the Un-stapled zip package

At this point, I recommend that your script delete the `.zip` or `.dmg` file which it uploaded.  Reason: That file was archived from a product which does not yet have your notarization ticket *stapled* to it.  At the end of your script, you will create a new `.zip` or `.dmg` from a modified app which has the ticket.  Deleting the file immediately prevents you from shipping an un-stapled app by mistake.

#### Wait in a Loop for Apple's Response

Your script can then start pestering Apple's server for your final results, by running this command in a loop along with with some sleep:

`/usr/bin/xcrun altool --notarization-info  --username "your-apple-id-email" --password "@keychain:your-notarizing-name" --output-format "xml"

If your script runs this command immediately, it will get returned in stdout some xml which will look something like this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>notarization-info</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Date</key>
        <date>2019-08-07T01:17:37Z</date>
        <key>RequestUUID</key>
        <string>4ba71353-9d99-4b52-b579-37f384717130</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>in progress</string>
    </dict>
    <key>os-version</key>
    <string>10.15.0</string>
    <key>success-message</key>
    <string>No errors getting notarization info.</string>
    <key>tool-path</key>
    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework</string>
    <key>tool-version</key>
    <string>1.1.1138</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The significant key path in there is `notarization-info:Status`, whose value `in progress` means that Apple is still working on your submission.  After a few minutes usually (Apple says "should be less than an hour", but I experienced times of up to three and a half hours on the USA holiday afternoon of 2019-Jul-04), `altool` will retturn to your script a different xml in stdout,  something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>notarization-info</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Date</key>
        <date>2019-08-06T23:28:25Z</date>
        <key>LogFileURL</key>
        <string>https://osxapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Enigma113/v4/f6/09/be/f609bee3-b031-323a-0987-d1f620a78758/developer_log.json?accessKey=1565410613_1722173034418364591_TvycjBAzd6FRTYGKZEFU6EwDfsws8Wa1MV%2FYnTiJ1zyOZamc%2FoeO5RMeIzZN669ZQJgO2Q4W48ipKNFO%2BQGuq%2FITXN8MQAetbNe90w9ogzqXbrzTHg%2FgYK89yvEFmiiRxhaVlZqLI93NBpY0hwBqXv2bvvlg%2FRCc%2BVaCNRJ%2BrnE%3D</string>
        <key>RequestUUID</key>
        <string>07fc3745-b0ff-4d1a-9b15-37f384717130</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>success</string>
        <key>Status Code</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Status Message</key>
        <string>Package Approved</string>
    </dict>
    <key>os-version</key>
    <string>10.15.0</string>
    <key>success-message</key>
    <string>No errors getting notarization info.</string>
    <key>tool-path</key>
    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework</string>
    <key>tool-version</key>
    <string>1.1.1138</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After some reverse-engineering, you see that, in each loop iteration, your script should parse the XML and break out of the loop whenever the value of `Status` is something other than `in progress`, or if you prefer, when `LogFileURL` is defined.  Or if you prefer email triggers, your script can look for an email from Apple with subject line *You can now distribute your Mac software.*.

UPDATE 2019-11-02

After having trouble with this step in my last couple shipments, and again today, I have now confirmed a bug in Apple's Notary Service.  The bug is that the `altool --notarization-info` command will fail for 1-5 hours, returning nonzero exit codes, and in stdout an error code 1519 "Could not find the RequestUUID", as in the following example stdout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>os-version</key>
    <string>10.15.1</string>
    <key>product-errors</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>code</key>
            <integer>1519</integer>
            <key>message</key>
            <string>Could not find the RequestUUID.</string>
            <key>userInfo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSLocalizedDescription</key>
                <string>Could not find the RequestUUID.</string>
                <key>NSLocalizedFailureReason</key>
                <string>Apple Services operation failed.</string>
                <key>NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion</key>
                <string>Could not find the RequestUUID.</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>tool-path</key>
    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework</string>
    <key>tool-version</key>
    <string>4.00.1181</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is a bug because, of course my script *did* submit the Request UUID which it just received from Apple Notary Service, Apple *should* be able to find it and, furthermore, when I kept sending the command manually, after about 2 hours, suddenly, the command returned `Success` and continued to return `Success` with subsequent commands, and I got the *Success* email from Apple.  This delay happened today with 7 different good Request UUIDs, the longest was 5 hours.  Possibly, at this time, there is a 1-5 hour delay between Apple Notary Service creating and sending you a Request UUID, and it appearing in the database which Apple Notary Service uses to respond to `notarization-info` requests, so you get this false error.  Very sad.

Since I have no control over when Apple assigns people to fix bugs, I have modified this stage of my script to parse the response from Apple and die only if the command returns nonzero exit status *and* the `code` of the first (index=0) `product-errors` array entry is not 1519.  If you are using PlistBuddy to parse XML as I am, the key path for that is code should be `product-errors:0:code`.  The loop in my script prints each time Error 1519 is received, so I can see what is going on, and of course, I've modified its `while` condition to not exit if the error code is 1519.

After so fixing my script, I had several apps to ship.  Apple Notary Service treated the first one nicely: No Errors 1519, and *Success* after about two minutes.  The next one, however, needed this new feature of my script.  At time 09:54 (HH:mm) my script received the Request UUID from Apple.  20 seconds later, it sent the first `altool --notarization-info` query.  The response was a false Error 1519.  Subsequent queries also returned false Errors 1519, for almost 3 hours, through 12:44.  Then, at 12:45, all of a sudden it received an `in progress` response.  After 5 more `in progress` responses, at 12:47, finally, *Success*.

One more thing before leaving this topic: An hour after that request succeeded with no Errors 1519, a prior request from an hour ago suddenly started returning `in progress` and then a few minutes later, *Success*.  Conclusion: Request UUIDs which get detoured into the Error 1519 morass are not queued FIFO with later Request UUIDs which might, by chance, avoid the Error 1519 detour.  So, a better workaround might be to abandon a Request UUID after receiving one more Error 1519 responses and start over by re-uploading the app to Apple Notary Service and getting another Request UUID which you hope will work better.  Of course, you'll get many emails during the next few hours as all of the Request UUIDs which you abandoned eventually succeed.

At any rate, now, on to the next step in the script…

#### Check Apple's Log file

Your script should parse out the value of the `LogFileURL` so it can check the log, because because even if notarization succeeds the Log file created by Apple might contain warnings.  To get the Log file your script should, of course,

```
curl <LogFileURL-Value>
```

The Log file is apparently JSON.  Warnings or Errors are presented as an array, which is the value of key `issues` .  So your script should parse that `curl` output with a JSON parser and if the value of key `issues` is a JSON null or an empty array, continue shipping.

#### Staple the Ticket to your App

This step is pretty easy…

```
xcrun stapler staple /path/to/YourApp.app
```

Running this command will add to your app's package a new file: `YourApp.app/Contents/CodeResources`.  This is apparently your *notarization ticket*.  Note that this file is in addition to the file `YourApp.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources` which is still there, and contains the code signature, the same as in pre-notarization days.

#### Verify the Ticket Stapling

But there is a better way to verify that your app now has a good ticket.  Your script should now run (or re-run) a Gatekeeper check:

```
spctl -a -v /path/to/YourApp.app
```

The result, in stderr, should be,

```
/path/to/YourApp.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
```

which is the same result as pre-notarization, except for the insertion of *Notarized*.  Astute scripts will parse that stderr and abort shipping if the above words are not detected.

#### Zip and Ship

Now that the ticket has been added, your script can zip or dmg your .app again, but this time, ship it.

Comment: altool has --output-format option which can use to get structured output that can be parsed for example with PlistBuddy for both notarize-app and notarization-info commands.

Comment: That is a big help, @khuttun.  I have not tried this yet, but when I get time, soon I hope, I shall modify my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: My dmg file is notarized but I don't see YourApp.app/Contents/CodeResources file. /Volumes/DMG_Name/YourApp.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID

Comment: @ParagBafna: That is interesting.  I only tested mine with a zip, not a disk image.  When you say *my dmg file is notarized*, do you mean that, in the last step, `spctl` test returns *Notarized Developer ID*?  If so, I wonder what the *stapler* operation did.  It must have done something – adding a file somewhere, I presume.

Comment: @JerryKrinock You can use --output-format xml, to get plist output

Comment: Thanks to @khuttun and @Parag Bafna, I've now edited this answer to use the `--output-format` option.

Comment: This is not work for '.saver' file, I get 'Unable to validate your application.' when I want to code sign it.

Comment: The command to "find the itc_provider of your team" can't be used because that Xcode tool "Application Loader" does not exist. It must have been removed.

Comment: I already fail with getting the password out of the keychain. Signing with "--keychain-profile Foobar" but how do i specify this here?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a reusable and freely-licensed notarize & staple script for automated builds:

https://github.com/rednoah/notarize-app/blob/master/notarize-app

It'll run and wait and only exit once everything is done:

1. Run `altool --notarize-app`
2. Run `altool --notarization-info` periodically until notarization is complete
3. Run `stapler staple`

Comment: Where should we put that script?

Comment: You'd run `notarize-app` in your build script after creating your `*.pkg` deployment artifact.

Comment: Sorry I just don't get it. do you mean I should put that script inside the build script inside build setting, then archive the app? (I want to notarize a screensaver)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890758/1514467 thoroughly explains how app notarization works. Best to do things manually step by step once so you understand how things work, and then you can move on to using `notarize-app` to automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has updated the notary process to automate this scripting...
Notarize myapp.app:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent myapp.app myapp.zip
sudo xcrun notarytool submit myapp.zip --apple-id drwho@bbc.com --team-id ABCDEFGHIJ --password <token>
```

Notarize myapp.dmg:

```
zip myapp.dmg.zip myapp.dmg
sudo xcrun notarytool submit myapp.dmg.zip --apple-id drwho@bbc.com --team-id ABCDEFGHIJ --password <token> --wait
```

Previous examples in this answer use deprecated and now obsoleted methods.

Comment: Thanks for this! For future users, keep in mind that the linked code is GPL licensed (not easy to tell from the linked pages without popping back to the main repo) -- make sure you can use GPL code in your software before copying.

Comment: I came here because it's the top google answer when you ask how to get errors when notarytool submit goes wrong. THis is not your solution but i just can't understand all what Jerry wrote here. Nightmare Apple Developer Tools again.

Answer (score 0):

`altool` is now deprecated. You can use this script to codesign, notarize with the new `notarytool`, and then staple the app: https://github.com/thezik/notarizer